# Can't get Reactjs using Helmet to run script tags

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

I'm using Helmet in Reactjs to provide my meta data per page - which works fine up until i want to provide Schema markup into the  tag. I'm implementing as the documentation describes, but as my markup is coming from an api, i need to escape the code to return my function, to which i get this error;

> TypeError: tag[primaryAttributeKey].toLowerCase is not a function

The script works if it's just a string on the page, but when i call the function, it errors out

Here's my code;

```
async componentWillMount(){
        var data = await api.schema();
        this.setState({schema: data.data});
        console.log(this.state.schema);
    }


    getSchema(){
        if(this.state.schema.length){
            return this.state.schema.map((content,index) => {
                var pageschema = content.PageSchema;

                return(
                    pageschema
                );
            })
        }
    }

render() {
        return (

        <div>
            <Helmet>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <title>Title title title</title>
                <meta name="description" content="this is a page description"></meta>
                <link rel="canonical" href="xxx" />
                <script type="application/ld+json">{this.getSchema()}</script>
            </Helmet>
...
```

Page schema returns the following which has been JSON.parsed

```
"@context": "https://schema.org",
"@type": "Organization",
"name": "xx",
"alternateName": "xx",
"url": "xx",
"logo": ""
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To works, you need stringify your array before send for `Helmet`:

```js
getSchema(){
    const { schema } = this.state

    if(schema.length){
        return `${JSON.stringify(
            schema.map((content,index) => {
                const pageschema = content.PageSchema;

                return(
                    pageschema
                );
            })
        )}`
    }
}
```